# running two shell commands consecutively within a c++ program

Tags: c++, g++, system

The following shell commands are accompanied by actions they perform:

```
lex q5.l   ->produces lex.yy.c
g++ lex.yy.c -o q5  ->compiles lex.yy.c and produces a relocatable object file
```

Now I want to do this within a c++ program(main.cpp). So, I do the following in main.cpp:

```
system("lex q5.l");
system("gcc lex.yy.c -o q5");
```

But when I do `g++ main.cpp -o main` in the shell, the following errors are generated:

```
q5.l:1: premature EOF
g++: error: lex.yy.c: No such file or directory
```

When I checked the folder, there was no `lex.yy.c`. But if I explicitly run `lex q5.l` from shell, the folder contains `lex.yy.c`. So, I am thinking that `lex q5.l` didn't execute in my program `main.cpp`.

Can anyone point out the problem and a way to execute main.cpp correctly.

Comment: Does `echo | lex q5.l` work from the shell?  Seems like `lex` is poorly coded to check for EOF on its input.  You could try `flex`, or something like `lex q5.l < /dev/random` to avoid an EOF condition... just guess-work here though.

Comment: @TonyD...yes, echo | lex q5.l works from shell

Comment: @TonyD...I have uploaded main.cpp [here](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=CeTpj)

Comment: try with the `-ll` option ( `g++ lex.yy.c  –o q5  -ll` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your program you don't flush or close the stream writing `q5.l` before executing your `system` call... the output file can't be expected to have the intended content....